# How to display role separately when creating role in Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have the following code to create a role in my discord server:

```
cr_perms = discord.Permissions(display_role_seperately=False)
await message.guild.create_role(name=rolename, permissions=cr_perms)
```

I was wondering how I can enable the option below when creating a new role within my code:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
role = await message.guild.create_role(name=rolename)
role.hoist = True
```